# Check my answer for find a formula for $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{n}}{4^{n+2}}$

Tags: complex-analysis

The next question in John D'Angelo's text  is exercise 4.9. I got an answer but wanted to check it because there's no solution manual:

Find a formula
$$
\sum_{n=0}^ {\infty} \frac{z^{n}}{4^{n+2}}.
$$

I took the 1/16 out and get
$$
\frac{1}{16} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{z}{4}\right)^n = \frac{1}{16}\frac{1}{\left(1 - \frac{z}{4}\right)} = \frac{1}{16 - 4z}.$$

Could someone tell me if this is the correct answer. I sure hope so. Thanks.

Comment: You hope not without success. (It is correct.)

Comment: It is correct, given that $\bigl|\frac{z}{4}\bigr|<1$

Answer (score 1):

As has been discussed in the comments, your solution is correct except you need to specify that $\left|\dfrac{z}{4}\right| < 1$, or equivalently $|z| < 4$, so that the geometric series converges.